# ContentViewController design decisions for UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to do something similar to the Yelp filter on the iPad.  It looks like this: [image]

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do this.  It looks very neat, like it's two sections in a UITableView, with each row doing something different.  The first Sort Results By is just a UISegmentedControl, the second is some custom control that has multiple selections for the UISegmentContrl, and the Neighborhoods button acts like a UINavigationController, pushing another viewController onto the stack, that hides all the current info in the pic, and has a back button at the top.  I was wondering how someone would go about building this.  When I first see this, I would

1) create the first UISegmentedControl in the .xib
2) create the second custom control in code (saw a post on SO about how to create a segment control with multiple selections
3) have the Neighborhoods button allocate a new UINavigationController with the rootViewController being the new class I show.
4) add the appropriate "Sort Results By" and "Narrow Results By" UILabels in .xib
5) draw the rounded rects in the code behind in viewDidLoad or something

That's how I would approach it.  I'm not sure if that's a good way to approach it or not.  I am open to people's suggestions!  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a grouped table view.  Each of those bubbles is a separate cell.  You could do all of that with Interface Builder.  Just design each cell as a separate item, set up IBOutlets for them, and return the appropriate nib object in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  You also need to return the proper height of each cell in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: So I started implementing it by your recommendation.  How do I make it so you don't see the cell borders though?  I saw that ppl said you can make the backgroundView a blank view, but then you don't get the outline of the grouped table (cell.backgroundView = backView; where UIBackView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];.  You just get nothing for the borders.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.